# Configuring a Node JS App to Use NPM

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a really simple Node JS app and I'd like to include the [Express JS](http://expressjs.com/) framework. I've installed Express with NPM (and NPM with Homebrew) without any errors using:

```
brew install npm
npm install express
```

And my `server.js` file contains only:

```
var express = require('express');
```

When I run my application I get `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`. How can I tell my Node application to include the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell node where your libs are.

extract from http://nodejs.org/api.html

```
require.paths
An array of search paths for require(). This array can be modified to add custom paths.

Example: add a new path to the beginning of the search list

require.paths.unshift('/usr/local/node');
```

Comment: Does a solution exist that supports deploying specifically NPM packaged projects? I noticed that NPM supports a 'bundle' command but I couldn't figure out how to use it...

Comment: Can't help with that I'm afraid, I haven't tried bundle out. Lots of projects, seem to bundle their deps in and require those ones specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a walkthrough of using npm's bundle command:

http://intridea.com/2010/8/24/using-npm-with-heroku-node-js?blog=company