# node.js express require?

Tags: node.js, require, express, npm

In an example I see something like this:

`var uid = require("../support/express/support/connect/lib/connect/utils").uid`

`var express = require("express")` is OK!

`var uid = require("express").uid` is undefined

I installed express with npm.

How should I require the uid?

Comment: This question has been answered before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870052/configuring-a-node-js-app-to-use-npm

Comment: @Nek require("express") works for me without unshift, the question is about uid

Comment: Please edit your question to make it more clear. State that require("express") works. So does require(...).uid silently fail?

Comment: @Nek sorry, is that supposed to work? I'm not certain that it fails, it didn't look like it was working. I believe it's undefined.

Comment: I don't think it should work. What do you need uid for? What is your goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

express utilizes [connect](https://github.com/senchalabs/connect) under its hoods which gets installed along with express.

In this case, you want to access the `uid` function *of connect*:

```
> require('connect').utils.uid(40)
'3DQD2XfAd19uL1r7LK6ZkIrFooSOGGVkGePI36HL'
```

Since:

```
> require('connect')
{ version: '0.5.5',
  utils: 
   { md5: [Function],
     defaultMime: 'application/octet-stream',
     toBoolean: [Function],
     merge: [Function],
     uid: [Function],
     ...

> require('connect').utils
{ md5: [Function],
  defaultMime: 'application/octet-stream',
  toBoolean: [Function],
  merge: [Function],
  uid: [Function],
  ...
```

etc.